# Is JBoss 7.1 is vulnerable to POODLE: SSLv3 vulnerability (CVE-2014-3566) in Windows

Tags: jboss7.x, windows-server-2008-r2, poodle-attack

We are using JBoss 7.1 in our application on Windows platform.
Is this particular version of JBoss vulnerable to POODLE??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All SSL implementations are vulnerable to POODLE attack.

For details how to disable SSLv3 for in EAP6 (AS7) see https://access.redhat.com/articles/1232123

Comment: @ctomc- can you paste full solution? please. Not able to access the link.

Comment: Hi - Did you managed it figure it out. I can find any resources online which refer to JBoss AS 7.1. Would appreciate you sharing the config if you have figured out a way!